# Changing .SO files in android cause to damage the apk

Tags: android, decompile

i created an android app(simple cocos2d-x project) that in this project i have  a method that takes a string and then render it, in initialize state of my app i pass the "abcde" as parameter to this method. This works fine in windows and android devices.
but when i open SO file that placed in apk and edit any of character of "abcde" string and then replace so file with older so in apk file, the apk does't install on android devices.
I get this error when trying to install the apk : application not installed.

anyone can explain me why this happen??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android APKs are signed to ensure the developer (holder of the private key) is the only person who can update the application. When the apk is signed, much like that of a jar file, hashes are taken of all the files.

What is likely happening is that you are modifying a file and not resigning the application - this will cause the package manager to reset due to hash mismatches when checking the signatures.

Comment: Thanks to reply , so how can i resign the new app??

Comment: You are right, i used apk studio to create new app with new sign.